# Docker nginx service won't accept connections while individual replicas do

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

My docker swarm has an API service that uses Nginx proxy to access Report service. Nginx proxy only doing proxy_pass and running in 2 replicas. I have problem accessing Nginx proxy by service name or service IP. Sometimes it works, but mainly i get this response:

```
# curl 'http://nginx-proxy:8000/v1/report?id=662867'
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
# curl 'http://10.0.17.13:8000/v1/report?id=662867'
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

On other hand if i access individual replicas by an IP or from outside docker network - it works just fine:

```
# curl 'http://10.0.17.14:8000/v1/report?id=662867'
0   662867  0   10  6   6   0.0 194 3   5   437
# curl 'http://10.0.17.18:8000/v1/report?id=662867'
0   662867  0   10  6   6   0.0 194 3   5   437
```

Feels like internal docker balancer gets overwhelmed by amount of requests and stops accepting new connections. There is no errors in nginx logs - every request with 200 status. But API logs show this:

```
INFO Cannot get online report: Get http://nginx-proxy:8000/v1/report?id=732743: dial tcp 10.0.17.13:8000: connect: cannot assign requested address caller=/go/src/api/src/reader.go:300 (*ReaderCursor).readOnline
INFO Cannot get online report: Get http://nginx-proxy:8000/v1/report?id=732703: dial tcp 10.0.17.13:8000: connect: cannot assign requested address caller=/go/src/api/src/reader.go:300 (*ReaderCursor).readOnline
```

I'm using official Nginx image, only modified `worker_processes  auto;` from 1 to auto.

Any ideas what can be wrong or where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Problem wasn't in docker at all. It was in an API code, which was running multiple processes with default 2 connections per post. Lots of requests used up all local ports to use for the client connection.

Fixed probelm with `http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 100`